# flex: how to create a skinned / customized menu?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

My client asks me to customize a flex flex 4 menu (menu and NOT menubar)

I have used soem CSS and some SKINs on other Flex components (buttons), but I have no idea where to start with menu items.

[image]

Here is the desired look&feel of the menu

Any clue on where to start ?

reagrds

Comment: What menu are you talking about? There is no Flex 4 Menu class, only mx / Flex 3.

Comment: menu = new Menu();

or if there is no menu, how to create something similar ?
(this list of users is provided by an arrayCollection)

Comment: What I see in your screenshot can simply be done with a List, but I have a feeling there's more to your question than that.